# Trying to pull down 1.2V Dataline to GROUND, Does not fully drop to 0V

Tags: stm32, ground

Im trying to pull down a 1.2V dataline to 0V with a STM32 development board (H743ZI).
The impulse is only some nanoseconds long, about ~50ns (longer duration or constant: does not matter same result.)

I checked with an oscilloscope: If I ground the connection with the microcontroller the voltage only drops to ~0.6V, which is not enough to reach low logic level.

The line I am talking about is an control line between CPU and RAM. My intentions are to interfere these control lines to stop certain commands. So I have two outputs contending against each other.

New Info:

The RAM Chip ist an Elpida X5116ADSE-3C-E ([datasheet](https://web.archive.org/web/20120720142957/http://www.elpida.com/eolpdfs/E1033E40_EOL.pdf)). There ist nothing connected between RAM and CPU. So it is just a line without a resistor or capacitor, between RAM and CPU. Just my STM32, the CPU and RAM. I try to interrupt an request pin which is just an input pin. So the line is not bidirectional. And my STM32 is running at 3.3V.

My setup:

- I put an 8 ohm resistor in between the dataline and the microcontroller.
- I connected ground of circuit board to my microcontroller ground.

What could I do? Do I need to change something in my setup or should I use an FPGA for things like this? What is the problem I can not fully ground the line ?

This is my code, not sure if it matters.

```
GPIOF->ODR &= ~(1 << 13); //PIN 13 => 0 => LOW
GPIOF->MODER |= (1 << 26); //PIN 13 => 01 => OUTPUT

//17 cycles @ (2ns @ 480MHz) => 34ns
while(counter < 4){
    __NOP();
    counter++;
}

GPIOF->MODER &= ~(1 << 26); //PIN 13 => 00 => INPUT
```

My schematic (do not have eagle installed sorry.)

[image: My Schematic]

Comment: What is driving the Dataline?

Comment: Its a control line between CPU and RAM

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Show schematic.

Comment: added simple schematic

Comment: @increaseboy it sounds like contention between the RAM and the CPU - RAM is trying to drive Dataline high, the CPU is trying to drive it low at the same time.

Comment: my intentions are to interfere these control lines to stop certain commands

Comment: If you are deliberately having two outputs contending against each other then you need to explain this in your question, not in the comments. It's certainly not clear at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have edited my question and hope it is more clear now.

Comment: This is a way to do this but we need a full schematic of your circuit, otherwise we're guessing at what connects where. For example, what else connects to the Dataline from the RAM apart from the STM32? Is this dataline bidirectional? Is the STM32 running from 1.2V or 3.3V?

Comment: I dont now much about the circuit also atm. I know I attached the wire to one of the request pins which are only inputs.. so these are only receiving commands, so I guess the CPU send signals to the RAM. i read that other people did the same and it should work I think. But anyways I will tell you guys more about the circuit when I am home thanks for your help so far

Comment: @SteveG I finally found some time and added some new information 
 I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If both are outputs the answer is: you can't.

If there are more than one devices, which can control the same line it has to be open collector or open drain.

If you connect two active outputs it is very likely to damage the pin. You drive the line low, the device high. Your resistor is 8 Ohm. The input and output resistance of the pins are usually 1-5 Ohm. Let take 3 Ohm. The current will be 1.2V / 14 Ohm = 85mA (much too much for the pin).

Comment: Okay thank you for your answer. Thanks for letting me know I could damage something. But I read that other people accomplished the same thing but you do not find a lot of it online

Answer (score 1):

Without a proper schematic it is difficult to know exactly what your circuit looks like, but it sounds like you have a CPU sending requests to a RAM chip on a uni-directional dataline which you want to disable using an STM32.

The following schematic shows that you need to introduce a resistor R1 into your existing dataline between the CPU and RAM. For normal CPU/RAM operation the STM32 must keep its output pin P0 high impedance, and the best way to do this is to make it an input.

To disrupt the CPU/RAM data the STM32 has to make P0 an output with the value "0". It is important that the STM32 does not set a value "1" on P0, because that will force 3.3V onto the dataline which is operating at 1.2V.

The idea of R1 is that its value should be low enough that it allows the CPU/RAM to operate normally, but also limit the current when the STM32 needs to disturb the operation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXRIJa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>